# How to import data with a special record type?

Tags: record-type, import

I want to import a contact list with a special record type in my salesforce contact object db
how can I make this condition? I mean import the list in it's own record type 
for example list of teachers must be import in it's record type , or list of the students must be import in it's record type and etc.

Comment: How are you importing the data - DataLoader or DataImport Wizard or another tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on the tool that you are using, if you are using the Data Import Wizard it is easier than with Data Loader or third party tools.

**Data Import Wizard**

This tool will let you select from the Record Types available to your profile when you are importing the data, see the screen shot. This means that you have to load data for different record types separately to make use of this feature.

[image]

**Data Loader and third party tools**

In the data loader or most third party tools you need to include a column in the data for the RecordTypeId and include the RecordType Salessforce Id, you can get that by going to the Object and selecting the record type then copying it from the URL, like in the first image below, though it is easier to with Data Loader or another data tool.

[image]

Comment: thank you Dave. I think the first solution it the best practice. I mean the Data Import Wizard. I will check it right now.